# How do I disallow users from copying the references returned by a getter?

Tags: java

```
public class Bar {
    // Third party class -- I don't want to rely on its current interface.
}

public class Foo {
    private /* not final */ Bar bar;

    public refreshBar() {
        bar = new Bar();  // Old references are now "dead".
    }

    /** Question: The reference this method returns can change. */
    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}


Foo foo = new Foo();

foo.getBar().doThing();  // OK.
Bar bar = foo.getBar();  // BAD - I want this to be forbidden.
bar.doThing();           // ERROR.
```

How can I make the `BAD` line break at compile time? If that can't be done, then how can I make it throw an Exception? Can it even be affected at all?

Comment: Don't expose Bar, and don't have a public "getter' method for it. Rather only expose its `doThing()` method. This is exactly what encapsulation is for.

Comment: For me it is not clear how deep your **ONLY** goes. In general you should use the visibility modifiers for such stuff. So `private`, `protected` and so on, that is what they are for. However by that you can not forbid others to bypass the system by using the **Reflection API**. You can not truelly prevent others to access it by bypassing. However in general the modifiers should be enough. If others access a private variable without **reflection** the program will crash as a security exception is thrown.

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve? Why do you need this? When you do `foo.getBar().doThing()` the VM actually stores the reference locally, so it's not all that different from `Bar bar = foo.getBar(); bar.doThing();`.

Comment: @Radiodef The problem is that `Bar` may be recreated many times, making older instances "dead".

Comment: @Radiodef I'm pretty sure this did not refer to *local* use. The goal is probably to prevent users from storing the `Bar` that they obtained once, in an own field or so, and assuming that it will *always* be the same as the one that they could fetch from `Foo`. (But it may not be. They'd always have to fetch the "fresh", "current" `Bar`)

Comment: If you don't want to let others store `bar` reference then don't return it from Foo. Instead add `doThing()` method to Foo which will use correct `bar` like `public void doThing(){bar.doThing();}`

Comment: why having a getter at all? get rid of it. Delegate all Bar functions to Foo and use `foo.doNothing()` instead.

Comment: @Marco13 Well sure, so I guess the point I was trying to make is that it's not obvious to me why this is necessary, given the examples.

Comment: Same to @Pshemo. Please see first comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels @Serge I want to avoid that, `Bar` comes from a third party source and its interface is not reliable.

Comment: @Hovercraft. sorry, too much reading for today :-).

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: that doesn't parse. How can calling `foo.getBar().doSomething();` be more reliable than `foo.doSomething();`? You're not telling the whole story or else this is one massive [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) goose chase.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `foo.getBar().doSomething();` gives the correct error message when the interface changes, `foo.doSomething();` will not.

Comment: There is no way in java to do it. Convert to c++ :-)

Comment: Until you improve this question and tell enough information so that we understand it fully, the best solution is as I mentioned in my first comment, and as several others have already mentioned.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've been improving it, what information is missing?

Comment: If bar is from a third party source, create a wrapper in your own code.

Comment: @NShumway exactly. a decorator pattern, as we've been suggesting all along.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez You have to show us an example which is complete enough that we really understand your motivation. Especially so if you think Hovercraft and Serge's suggestion doesn't work. I also agree very strongly with them that it seems like a good idea. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: I'll make a new question with more context.

Comment: The downvotes and comments are a bit harsh. I think that this is a legitimate question. It could be improved, of course, but the intention should be clear for everybody who ever had to work with legacy code and ... "unconventional" object life cycles. (Strong hint: Polluting your class with lots of `public` methods that are dictated by some third party class is **not** a sustainable solution)

Answer (score 3):

Simple. **Don't** expose `Bar` and just expose whichever methods you want:

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public refreshBar() {
        bar = new Bar();
    }

    public void doOneThing() {
        bar.firstThing();
    }

    public void doAnotherThing() {
        bar.secondThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Bar` class was originally commented with `// Big mess of public methods`, now changed to `// Third party class -- I don't want to rely on its current interface.`. This means that you'd have to add *many* methods that are not under your control, just to forward the functionality (that you can't even rely on). Sounds brittle to me.

Comment: If the interface of something you depend on is volatile, your code will always be brittle. Solutions: 1) use a better library 2) tell the authors to stop being stupid 3) lock yourself in to a specific version and live with the consequences

Comment: Sure, in a perfect world... ... But seriously, I think that introducing a wrapper/interface can even serve as a "cushion" and absorb some otherwise incompatible changes of `Bar`. In ... a perfect world ;-) one could even implement the wrapper to *emulate* old behavior, and thus, stay source-compatible despite different `Bar`-versions. Of course, all this depends on the exact application case. Right now, we can only list some possible options. Forwarding the required methods directly is one of them. Introducing an interface is another (that I consider to be more flexible, but with more effort)

Answer (score 1):

The short and discouraging answer is: Not at all. It's simply not possible. There are means for achieving the behavior that you want, but only when the classes are *designed* for this application pattern. Fixing this in hindsight, for "legacy code", may not be so easy.

One obvious solution was already mentioned in the comments: Do not expose the `Bar` via `getBar`. You **could** instead provide all the public methods

```
public class Foo {
    private /* not final */ Bar bar;

    //public Bar getBar() { return bar; } // NOPE

    public void doThis() { bar.doThis(); }
    public void doThat() { bar.doThat(); }
}
```

But I would **not recommend this**, for the obvious reason: You commented the `Bar` class to have a

```
// Big mess of public methods.
```

and you certainly do **not** want to pollute your `Foo` class with all these methods.

<sub>Edit: The comment was later changed to instead say that `Bar` is a third-party class with an interface that the asker does not want to rely on. The solution sketched here may be applied nevertheless, and in this case, also serve as a cushion that - to some extent - may even help to guard against incompatible changes</sub>

---

I could imagine another approach, that might be a tad cleaner:

1. Extract an interface from `Bar`, containing all the public methods that you need. This is usually possible with an IDE (e.g. Eclipse: "Extract interface"). Let's call it `BarInterface`.
2. Return an instance of the `BarInterface` from your `Foo` class:

   ```
   public BarInterface getBar() { ... }
   ```
3. Do not return the `bar`, but a wrapper around the `bar`. Basically, an implementation of the `BarInterface` that simply delegates to a `Bar` instance. This is basically an Adapter Pattern.

---

```
interface BarInterface {
    public void doThis();
    public void doThat();
}

public class Bar 
    public void doThis() { ... }
    public void doThat() { ... }
}

class BarWrapper implements BarInterface {
    private Bar delegate; 
    void setDelegate(Bar delegate) { this.delegate = delegate; }
    @Override public void doThis() { delegate.doThis(); }
    @Override public void doThat() { delegate.doThat(); }
}


public class Foo {
    private /* not final */ Bar bar;

    // This can be final!
    private final BarWrapper barWrapper = new BarWrapper();

    public refreshBar() {
        bar = new Bar();  // Old references are now "dead".
        barWrapper.setDelegate(bar);
    }

    // The reference returned here will never change!
    public BarInterface getBar() {
        return barWrapper;
    }
}
```

Of course, that's a bit of effort (particularly when there are many methods in the `Bar` class). But it may allow you to solve the original issue: People can still fetch their beloved `Bar(Interface)`-reference and store it. Any call to `refreshBar()` will cause these references to be updated transparently.

But of course you have to see whether or not it is really applicable or beneficial in your exact application case.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but if `Bar` is a third-party class, you can't define what it implements. You've also not solved the problem that there are a lot of methods. You've just added boilerplate.

Comment: @Michael Whether or not `Bar` carries the `implements` in its signature or not is only a detail in this example, but I edited it to make this clearer.

Comment: Right... So you identified the problem with the first example as being "you do not want to pollute your Foo class with all these methods". Your second example does exactly the same thing, but with a matching interface. How does that solve the problem?

Comment: @Michael The class `Foo` has a single method - namely, `getBar` - for exposing the functionality of `Bar`. Regardless of how many methods are in `Bar`, and how many are actually needed, there's always only this single `getBar` method.

Comment: OP doesn't want people to be able to keep a copy of a reference to a `Bar`. Why would providing an object which is *basically* a `Bar` be any better? "`Bar bar = foo.getBar();  // BAD - I want this to be forbidden.`"

Comment: @Michael The key points of this suggestion are: 1.: The object returned by `getBar()` here is `final` (!), and 2.: **Although** the object is `final`, it is still updated transparently and automatically when `refreshBar` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of a simple wrapper for your purposes:

```
public class BarWrapper {
    public static void doThing() {
        foo.getBar.doThing();
    }
}

public static void Main( String[] Args) {
    foo.getBar // ERROR: does not import FOO
    BarWrapper.doThing(); // WORKS
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If `Bar` is an interface, you can create a `Proxy` object for that interface and return it.  Then, when any method on that proxy interface is invoked, you could get the current `Bar` object, and pass the call on to that instance.

See: [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) documentation.